# Format output of an array into a string

Tags: powershell, format

I'm trying to format an array into a string.
What I'm doing is this:

```
$PysicalMemory | Format-Table @{n="Capacity(GB)";e={$_.Capacity/1GB}}, Speed
```

This gives me the output in this form:

```
Capacity(GB) Speed
------------ -----
           4  1600
           4  1600
```

But I would like to format it in a single string like this, but I have no luck:

```
4GB1600/4GB1600
```

Comment: Can you post where you got `$PysicalMemory` from?

Answer (score 3):

this requires a slightly different method than you used, but it DOES give the output you seem to want & is easily tweaked ...

```
$CIM_RAM = @(Get-CimInstance CIM_PhysicalMemory)

$RAM_Info = foreach ($CR_Item in $CIM_RAM)
    {
    '{0}GB{1}Mhz' -f ($CR_Item.Capacity / 1GB), $CR_Item.Speed
    }

$RAM_Info -join '/'
```

output = `2GB800Mhz/2GB800Mhz/2GB800Mhz/2GB800Mhz`

yes, my ddr2 ram is really that slow. [*grin*]

Comment: I would also add that if you want to store it for use later, you should store it in a variable like this `$PhysicalMemoryString = $RAM_Info -join '/'`

Comment: @Joseph - the reason i used a different format for the strings was to make it very, very obvious that the exact layout of the string can easily be tweaked as desired. your suggestion _exactly_ fits the OPs request, but may not make the teaching point. i approved the edit ... but i am still not sure that was the correct thing to do. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Maybe add it as a another line perhaps? Maybe it would cause a little confusion, lol. I don't know. I'd have to know the OP's Powershell skills, I guess... I certainly see your point though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.  I saw Lee's post before it got edited and understand both of them (although my Powershell skills are very limited I must admit).